# Are there infinitely many prime numbers of the form $p^2+4$ with $p$ prime?

Tags: number-theory

Let $p$ be a prime. Are there infinitely many prime numbers which are of the form $p$$^2$$+$$4$?

Comment: Where is your attempt?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Your question will likely be better received if you show what you have tried to resolve the problem, and/or the context of the problem.

Comment: I just put that, thank you.

Comment: $p^2+4 \equiv -1(\mod 6)$ only implies that if there are infintely or finitely many primes of the form $p^2+4$, then all of them will leave a remainder $5$ when divided by $6$.

Comment: I find the question hard to understand. What does being "donated $p^2 + 4$" mean? Is it asking about primes of the form $p^2 + 4$?

Comment: Thanks for your edit, Abhishek.
You can say that, Tob.

Comment: I have no idea how your motive to believe that the conjecture holds is actually related to the conjecture.

Comment: @Did. I agree and would argue that the best version of this question was the first version before we added in text which seems to only obfuscate. I think we are seeing the worst version of "What did you try?" play out.

Comment: @Mason Indeed, fake "what I tried" paragraphs do not add value, in other words, questions with them should be closed just as a question with no personal input.

Comment: Alright, I deleted it.

Comment: Just because for a given prime, $p$ you know that $p^2+4$ is one less than a multiple of $6$ doesn't mean that $p^2 + 4$ is prime.

Comment: Well, was that an open problem!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easy answer: We don't know.

Check out: https://oeis.org/A045637.

It looks like this problem is open but an answer would follow from us resolving the Bunyakovsky conjecture. You can read up on that [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1223781/is-there-a-link-between-the-bunyakovsky-conjecture-and-the-twin-prime-conjecture?rq=1) or on [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bunyakovsky_conjecture).

Comment: This is a field which has full of conjectures.